# How can I block or solve concurrent MySQL connection without the fake free Wordpress cache plugins?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, plugins

How can I solve " you have exceeded your concurrent MySQL connection limit " without using a fake free cache plugin that requires to pay a private CDN ?

If I could hack one of the Wordpress cache plugins to use Google Drive instead of MaxCDN for which I can't afford price and I will never pay even when I'll have a job or money one day, because I did not choose it, could also be a solution.

But maybe I could block something on the site.

Or if there is a free blog or free website template that doesn't do this expensive error, I would proudly quit Wordpress for playing that game on me. I think it's robots that are doing the error because blog is still empty.

I'm not happy with the issue.

Comment: You can find out what of your plugins/something else is not optimized at all and does more queries than it ever should. Or move away from this shared hosting environment if grew out of it or their limit is too low for you

Answer (score 0):

I am now trying Gator Cache plugin on Wordpress, tomorrow I will try to find out how to... " add these rules to your apache virtual hosts config file "? But if you have an idea of the filename to edit, please tell me =) tx

```
    # BEGIN Gator Cache
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.gz$">
    ForceType text/html
  </FilesMatch>
  FileETag None etc...
```